# Android:listview store value of button

Tags: android, android-listview

[image]

I have a like button in my list View Item, Whenever i click on like button it saves the values in mysql.
(cus_id, offer_id, status)

But if i go to some other activity and return back to list view activity the like button turns to be in default color.

I want to save activity done on like button, means if the like button is clicked once it should remain clicked. even after switching b\w any activity.

how can i resolve it...

Comment: You must be using a data adapter for the your list view. If so, do you save this like action in your adapter?

Comment: i save my like action in database

Comment: how ur return back to listview activity by using `Intent` or `finish()`

Answer (score 1):

You should set adapter to your list in onResume activity call back rather than onCreate Activity call back. Making this change should solve the problem.

Answer (score 0):

I think you set your adapter for listview in onCreate,

1. You set your adapter in oncreate
2. Make changes to your listview item (Clicking Like Button)
3. Move to next activity.
4. Press Back and come to your list activity, your change not reflecting.

Because when you press back onCreate will not be gets called so your listview adapter refreshes its view with POJO that you have given to the adapter.

**Solution**

1) Set adapter in OnResume

2) I Suggest this solution, after updating SQL database, update your adapter POJO and call 
 **adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();**

Comment: can you provide any useful link or any code ...so  that i can understand the things better

Comment: Sorry i can't find any tutorial for you, 
but from my knowledge, 
1) after you click like button, 
2) you update your database 
3) then you scroll through your listview, even then your changes will not reflect

Kindly Search for Refreshing ListView using notifyDataSetChange().

Comment: You scroll your list and again come back to list item that you updated. you can see that your changes will not reflect.

Comment: In adapter class you need to update your like button. or else it will be only default value.

For adapter class you will provide List of Pojo, in that Pojo add a boolean field for your like button.